# how to detect a diagonal number of X's

Tags: c

i'm an trying to write a program that will call a function win if there is n number of X's or O's in a row.  I  am have difficulty with the diagonal win that slopes upwards.  can any offer any advice on what I should change?   Thanks in advance.  It calls an infinite loop instead of returning true.

```
bool left_diag_win(char **board, int num_rows, int num_cols) {
    int i;

    if (board[0][0] == '*') {
        return false;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < num_rows; ++i) {
        if (board[i][i] != board[0][0]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool right_diag_win(char **board, int num_rows, int num_cols) {
    int i;

    if (board[0][num_cols - 1] == '*') {
        return false;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < num_rows; ++i) {
        if (board[i][num_cols - i - 1] != board[0][num_cols - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: *I am having difficulty* is an absolutely meaningless phrase unless you follow it up by explaining what *difficulty* you're having. We don't offer advice here. We answer specific questions. What **specific problem** are you having with the code you've posted?

Comment: "Please explain the nature of the programming emergency."

Comment: I mean that My program is not recognizing that there are 4 X's or O's when there is an upwards diagonal.

Comment: Do not add information in comments. Instead, [edit] your question and provide it there where it can be seen. Also, what does the debugger show you when you step through that code?

Comment: The code assumes `num_rows <= num_cols`.  If both are always equal, just pass the size of the square matrix instead of both dimensions.

Comment: Can you show an example of how the board was declared and filled?

Comment: It works for me. I created a 4X4 array with `'X'`s on the skew-diagonal, and the `right_diag_win()` function returned `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You code seems correct, but you probably have a problem elsewhere.  Here is an example where it behaves as expected:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool left_diag_win(char **board, int num_rows, int num_cols) {
    if (board[0][0] == '*') {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < num_rows; ++i) {
        if (board[i][i] != board[0][0]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool right_diag_win(char **board, int num_rows, int num_cols) {
    if (board[0][num_cols - 1] == '*') {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < num_rows; ++i) {
        if (board[i][num_cols - i - 1] != board[0][num_cols - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    char *matrix1[] = { "X****", "*X***", "**X**", "***X*", "****X" };
    char *matrix2[] = { "****X", "***X*", "**X**", "*X***", "X****" };

    printf("matrix:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", matrix1[i]);
    }
    printf("left-diagonal: %d\n", left_diag_win(matrix1, 5, 5));
    printf("right-diagonal: %d\n\n", right_diag_win(matrix1, 5, 5));

    printf("matrix:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", matrix2[i]);
    }
    printf("left-diagonal: %d\n", left_diag_win(matrix2, 5, 5));
    printf("right-diagonal: %d\n\n", right_diag_win(matrix2, 5, 5));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
matrix:
X****
*X***
**X**
***X*
****X
left-diagonal: 1
right-diagonal: 0

matrix:
****X
***X*
**X**
*X***
X****
left-diagonal: 0
right-diagonal: 1
```